# Python OpenCv cv2 equivalent for CV_FILLED

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

This works as expected:

```
cv2.rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, color, thickness=cv2.cv.CV_FILLED)
```

But I have not been able to find the equivalent constant in the `cv2` interface.  I know this is simply some negative value ([from the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=rectangle#cv2.rectangle)), but I like the readability of the constant in the code and would like to write the equivalent function in pure `cv2`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no equivalent at the moment. Most likely it will be added in next major release (2.5) and will be named `cv2.FILLED`.

Any way it is safe to assume that the exact value (`cv2.cv.CV_FILLED == -1`) will not be changed.

Comment: Is there a good resource for porting from cv to cv2? (It would be great if there was a complete list of "for X replace it with Y".)